# Installing new Ruby versions failing after migrating from Macbook with M1 chip to Intel chip

Tags: homebrew, apple-m1, rbenv

So I migrated my user from a m1 chip to intel chip on Mac.

After that when I tried to run `rbenv install 2.7.6` on my terminal. I get this error message

`mkdir: /opt/homebrew: Permission denied`

I understand that the default directory for m1 chip is `/opt/homebrew` and for intel chip its `/usr/local`

This is what I did to resolve this

1. I tried to uninstall my homebrew but got a homebrew not found error message. Probably a directory problem again
2. Did a `sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew` instead
3. Install homebrew again
4. Run `brew config` to make sure `HOMEBREW_PREFIX` is `/usr/local`
5. Made sure that the `/opt/homebrew` folder isn't created this time
6. Uninstall and reinstall my rbenv

But when I try to run `rbenv install 2.7.6` again, I still get the same error. Same when I try to use `rvm` to download new ruby versions.

After which I successfully uninstall and reinstall my homebrew and rbenv several times again but the same error still persist.

How do I resolve this?